# Multiplication vs exponentiation in pairing based cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

$$P\in G_1$$$$Q\in G_1$$          $$a,b \in Z_q$$         $G_1$ isadditive cyclic group of prime order $q$
$$e(P^{a+b},Q)------(1)$$
$$e(aP+bP,Q)----(2)$$
(1) and (2) will give the same pairing result $e(P,Q)^{a+b}$.
In (1) and (2), despite of same pairing result, is there difference in terms of security or performance for different operations (exponentiation, multiplication and addition) in $P$?
In (1), I don't know clearly about exponentiation is allowed or not with randomly generated $P$ value from additive group.

Comment: A reference would help, where those terms are used. Actually, I think you placed the exponent in term $(1)$ at the wrong position, it would make more sense to have $e(P,Q)^{a+b}$, where the notation in the target group $e(.,.)$ is written multiplicatively.

Comment: @tylo. Yes, I know the result will be equal to $e(P,Q)^{a+b}$. I wanna emphasis on how $P$ is differently prepared.  (1)Using exponentiation(2) using multiplication and addition. I wanna know security or performance difference for those two preparations.

Comment: It seems to me, that they are not different operations, they are just different kinds of notation. Differences in notation make no difference for the actual computation. But you are actually wrong: You can not use both multiplicative and additive notation for the same group. So no, your statement is actually wrong. Besides, you should probably think less about actual operations. Pairing based crypto is realized in elliptic curves, and the group operation is not just simple addition, multiplication or exponentiation modulo some number.

Comment: Tylo is wright in the sense that $P^{a+b}$ is not defined. P is an element of an additive Group, generally speakin the group of points of EC.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI. Do you mean that exponentiation cannot be used for additive group element $P$?

Comment: @tylo . Do you mean that  $aP+bP$ cannot be done?

Comment: @peterpe, if the working structure is only additive, you can't multiply elements. But you can allways compute n.P = P+P+...+P n-times.
In case of pairing, their computation is analog to an exponentiation. Look at the paper of Victor Miller ... Efficient computation uses the notion of Divisors of EC.
And so the computation of a.P+b.P. a, b are rationnal numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pairings in Identity-based encryption vs. Attribute-based encryption](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/pairings-in-identity-based-encryption-vs-attribute-based-encryption)

Comment: I meant exactly what Robert NACIRI wrote: You have only one group operation. You can apply that to the same point $P$ as often as you want, and thus get $aP$ in additive notation. But in that case, you can't multiply elements. Therefore, you can't compute $P^2$. If you have multiplicative notation, then $P^2$ can be computed, but not $2P$  (e.g. if we talk about generic groups, in elliptic curves we use additive notation).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing apples and oranges. A group has a single operation associated to it. Depending on your notational conventions you either need to write (1) $e((a+b)P,Q)$ and (2) $e(aP+bP,Q)$ if you write $G_1$ additively or (1) $e(P^{a+b},Q)$ and (2) $e(P^a \cdot P^b,Q)$ if you write $G_1$ multiplicatively. The cost of computing $(a+b)P$ or $aP+bP$ depends on your approach to scalar multiplication, but typically the former approach will be more efficient.